# Making div element invisible on particular input

Tags: javascript, html, css

What I want to do is simply to make div with id="one" invisible on input of "1" in input-field and correspondingly same for div's with id="2" and id="3" for input of "2", input of "3".

I look for a short and simple way but other ways are also welcomed.
I am a beginner in web designing and development. 
For any query please comment below.

```
<head>

    <title>
           sample
    </title>

    <script type="text/javascript">

        function myFunction0()

        {
            var x = document.getElementById("text_1").value;

            if ( x == 1 ){
                document.getElementById("one").style.visibility = "hidden";
            }

            if ( x == 2 ){
                document.getElementById("one").style.visibility = "hidden";
                document.getElementById("two").style.visibility = "hidden";
            }
            if ( x == 3 ){
                document.getElementById("one").style.visibility = "hidden";
                document.getElementById("two").style.visibility = "hidden";
                document.getElementById("three").style.visibility = "hidden";
            }
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div style="margin-left: 250px;">
        <form>
            <input id="text_1" name="text1" type="text"/>
            <input id="text_2" name="text2" onclick="myFunction0();" type="submit"/>
        </form>
        <br/>
        <br/>
        <br/>
        <div id="one" style="height:100px; width:200px; border:1px solid black;">
            box 1
        </div>
        <br/>
        <div id="two" style="height:100px; width:200px; border:1px solid black;">
            box 2
        </div>
        <br/>
        <div id="three" style="height:100px; width:200px; border:1px solid black;">
            box 3
        </div>
        <br/>
        <div id="four" style="height:100px; width:200px; border:1px solid black;">
            box 4
        </div>
        <br/>
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: just remove `var` in line `if ( var x == 1 ){`

Comment: You can use `document.getElementById("one").style.display = "none" `

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```html
<head>

    <title>
           sample
    </title>

    <script type="text/javascript">

        function myFunction0()
        {
          [ 'one', 'two', 'three','four' ].forEach(function( ide ) {
             document.getElementById( ide ).style.visibility = "visible";
            });
var arr = [ 'one','two','three','four'];
            var x = Number(document.getElementById("text_1").value);
            for(var i=1;i<=x;i++){
              
              document.getElementById(arr[i-1]).style.visibility = "hidden";
            }
            
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div style="margin-left: 250px;">
        <form>
            <input id="text_1" name="text1" type="text"/>
            <input id="text_2" name="text2" value="click" onclick="myFunction0()" type="button">
        </form>
        <br/>
        <br/>
        <br/>
        <div id="one" style="height:100px; width:200px; border:1px solid black;">
            box 1
        </div>
        <br/>
        <div id="two" style="height:100px; width:200px; border:1px solid black;">
            box 2
        </div>
        <br/>
        <div id="three" style="height:100px; width:200px; border:1px solid black;">
            box 3
        </div>
        <br/>
        <div id="four" style="height:100px; width:200px; border:1px solid black;">
            box 4
        </div>
        <br/>
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: can u make one with changes like if i want to give [div id="one"] rather than [div id="1"]

Comment: if u can please use id as alphabet or alphanumeric only , as taking id as number isn't allowed by my trainer

Answer (score 0):

```
   $("body").on("keyup","#text_1",function() {
         var x = $("#text_1").val();
         if ( x == 1 ){
                document.getElementById("one").style.visibility = "hidden";
            }

            if ( x == 2 ){
                document.getElementById("one").style.visibility = "hidden";
                document.getElementById("two").style.visibility = "hidden";
            }
            if ( x == 3 ){
                document.getElementById("one").style.visibility = "hidden";
                document.getElementById("two").style.visibility = "hidden";
                document.getElementById("three").style.visibility = "hidden";
            }
});
```